# MVC4 Posting a form not calling Controller method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following form in my View.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "Blog")) name)
    {
        <fieldset id="frmTester">
            <div class="formContainer">    
                <span><input id="username" name="username" /></span>                  
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Now I have the following Method in my BlogController...

```
    public ActionResult PostComment(string username)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

I really don't get MVC very well. I dont see why I cant get the above ActionResult method to execute. I'm just trying to handle a postback. Anyone have any idea why this doesn't work or an alternative approach.

Comment: Remove the `name)` after `"Blog"))`.

Comment: Also add the appropriate type to your input: `<input id="username" name="username" type="text" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [HttpPost] :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostComment(string username)
{
    string u = Request.Form["username"] ; 
    // return Content(u); //if you want dispaly username use this
    return View();
}
```

Comment: None of the above works. My View is called BlogPost and it already has an ActionResult associated with it called like this ... `public ActionResult BlogPost(int id, string title){ which does execute when 


            ViewData["id"] = id; return View(_repository);
        }` When I click submit button the above ActionResult executes even though im not calling it.

Comment: My problem is just with how MVC4 in .NET works when I've come from a asp.net background. I suppose the best way to describe it is. Does a View have a 1-To-1 relationship with a Controller method? Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 4):

Change your view code to this...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "Blog", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset id="frmTester">
        <div class="formContainer">    
            <span><input id="username" name="username" type="text" /></span>                  
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and your action method to....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostComment(string username)
{

    return View();
}
```